# How I can bind a TClientDataset Object to a TGrid Object in the Runtime?

Tags: delphi, dataset, firemonkey, vcl, delphi-xe6

hey i want to bind a TClientDataset Object to a Grid in Delphi but I don't know how I can make it :(

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm3.RtcResultArtikelReturn(Sender: TRtcConnection; Data,
  Result: TRtcValue);
var
  dtable : TClientDataSet;
begin
  //FDMemTable1.Active := False;
  //FDMemTable1.Fields.Clear;

  //RtcDataSetFieldsToDelphi(Result.asDataSet,FDMemTable1);  //funktioniert
  RtcDataSetFieldsToDelphi(Result.asDataSet,dtable);

  //RtcDataSetRowsToDelphi(Result.asDataSet,FDMemTable1);  //funktioniert
  RtcDataSetRowsToDelphi(Result.asDataSet,dtable);

  Grid1 //????

  //FDMemTable1.Active := True;
  //RtcDataSetMonitor1.Active := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a clientdataset on your form and add a Datasource linked with the clientdataset. Then link the datasource with the grid with livebindings. Remove the clientdataset, leaving the bindsource.

Then in your code set the dataset for the datasource.